# Discord.js Bot "Unhanded Promised Rejection Type Error: Cannot Read Property 255890520990154752 of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

function Play(connection, message) 
{
    var servers = servers[message.guild.id];
    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(`${server.queue[0]}`, {filter: "audioonly"}));
    server.queue.shift();
    server.dispatcher.on("end",  function(){
        if(server.queue[0])
        {
            Play(connection, message);
        }else
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    });

}

class PlayCommand extends commando.Command
{
    constructor(client)
    {
        super(client,{
            name: 'play',
            group: 'music',
            memberName: 'play',
            description: 'Plays music!'
        });
    }

    async run(message, args)
    {
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
            return message.channel.send('I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!');
        }

        if(message.member.voiceChannel)
        {
            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)
            {
                if(!servers[message.guild.id])
                {
                    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
                    servers[message.guild.id] = {queue: []}
                }
                message.member.voiceChannel.join()
                    .then(connection => {
                        var servers = servers[message.guild.id];
                        message.reply("Sucessfully Joined Channel!");

                        let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args);
                        if(!validate) return message.channel.send('Sorry, Please input a **valid** url.');

                        server.queue.push(args);
                        Play(connection, message);
                    })
            }
        }
        else{
            message.reply("You must be in a voice channel to use that command! ")
        }

        console.log(message.author.username + ' Used a ' + 'music' + ' command \n');
    }
}

module.exports = PlayCommand;
```

This is the code for the "play" command on the bot.
The job of the bot is to play music using the ytdl library.

I am unsure where the issue is; at first, I thought it might not have found the library or a faulty installation so I re-installed all of the libraries (ytdl-core, discord.js, discord.js-commando...)

Still nothing!

I am not very fluent in Javascript especially error codes so any help or guidance in the right direction  to help fix the issue is greatly appreciated!

This is my first every question on here so I apologise for any inconsistencies.

For the full error code:

```
(node:18216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `servers` variable is never probably initialized. Make sure that it actually includes the correct guilds.